# Advanced Custom Fields : Repeaters

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to display below using ACF

(There are multiple sections so made this section a repeater)
**- Section Title**
( Under section title there are multiple packages so made this section a repeater as well)
**-- Package Title
-- Price**

Everytime when I'm add a section it should display as a new section underneath the previouse section. Instead of that it showing inside of previouse section.

Can you please point me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<div class="pricing">
            <?php
                if(have_rows('packages')): 
                    while(have_rows('packages')) : the_row();?>
                <div class="pricing-section">        
                <?php  echo the_sub_field('section_title_and_details'); ?>
                </div>
                
                <div class="pricing-package-container">        
                    <?php if(have_rows('package_details')): 
                                while(have_rows('package_details')) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="pricing-packages">
                                <h3><?php echo the_sub_field('package_name'); ?></h3>
                                <h4><?php echo the_sub_field('price'); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It looks like your `pricing-package-container` closes outside of the loop.  Also, `the_sub_field` doesn't require `echo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HowardE Pointed out above, pricing-package-container was closing outside of the loop.
Fixed it as below.

```
<!-- Custom Feilds -->
        <div class="pricing">
            <?php
                if(have_rows('packages')): 
                    while(have_rows('packages')) : the_row();?>
                <div class="pricing-section">        
                <?php the_sub_field('section_title_and_details'); ?>
                </div>
                
                    <div class="pricing-package-container">        
                    <?php if(have_rows('package_details')): 
                                while(have_rows('package_details')) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="pricing-packages">
                                <h3><?php the_sub_field('package_name'); ?></h3>
                                <h4><?php the_sub_field('price'); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                            <?php endwhile;
                        endif; ?>
                    </div>
                   <?php endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
        </div>
```